# How to get list of available serial ports in my pc using Java?

Tags: java, serial-port, javax.comm

I just run some codes to get a list of available ports n my cmputer and it returned me false when I have 3 com ports that are free. How do I solve this prob?

My codes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //SerialParameters params=new SerialParameters();
       // System.out.println(CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL );
        Enumeration portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        System.out.println(portList.hasMoreElements());
        while(portList.hasMoreElements()){
            System.out.println("Has more elements");
             CommPortIdentifier portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
               if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL) {
                    System.out.println(portId.getName());
               }
               else{
                     System.out.println(portId.getName());
               }

        }
}
```

Output :
false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears your setup of the javax.comm API may not be correct. Make sure you have done the following:

1. Placed the `comm.jar` file in the `jre/lib/ext` directory.
2. Placed the `javax.comm.properties` file in the `jre/lib` directory.
3. Placed the `win32com.dll` in the `jre/bin` directory.

Each of the above components "should" be available [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ubuntu and my computer does not have any serial/pararel port.

You need to simulate this ports in this case.

My answer:

[serial port identification with java on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669379/serial-port-identification-with-java-on-ubuntu/21567949#21567949)

Answer (score -1):

I have an additional answer, if you happen to do what I *naively* did.

I just forgot to add my user to the `dialout` group, and the result was to find no serial ports, while my `/dev/ttyUSB0` was forwarded correctly to my VirtualBox instance of a Lubuntu machine.