# How to get the list of all available serial ports on linux using java?

Tags: java, linux, serial-port

I want to get the list of all available serial ports on a linux machine using java 6

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get list of available serial ports in my pc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493279/how-to-get-list-of-available-serial-ports-in-my-pc)

Comment: I have checked that code it is not working on linux

Comment: the statement while (pList.hasMoreElements()) is always false in the code so it is not executing the rest of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have used rxtx on windows which worked well. there is a linux version: http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Installation_on_Linux

Answer (score 0):

The command under Linux is `dmesg | grep tty`

I think you need to implement the abstract class `Process` and call the  `Runtime.exec()` method, that returns a `Process` object.

Please read [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-out-linux-serial-ports-with-setserial/) and [here](http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010016).

Hope this helps.